# Substring index in case of repeated strings in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, substring

I need a SQL query to get the value between two known strings, which are repeated many times or twice.
An example.

```
base- 2019|ACX9|PTG-C|PPP1-MMM1|7986847
```

Desired result is PPP1 in Source and MMM1 in store_loc.

I've come up with this so far

```
select
base,
substring_index(substring_index (base,'-',1),'|',-1) as source, 
substring_index(substring_index (base,'-',-1),'|',1) as store_loc

from order_tracking
```

which is working fine with base like

```
2019|ACX9|PTGA|PPP1-MMM1|7986847
```

but not working with base like

```
2019|ACX9|PTG-C|PPP1-MMM1|7986847
```

Here it is giving source as PTG.

Can someone please help me with where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should store the individual elements of that string as separate columns. Then the query will be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to parse the second-to-last item in the delimited list.  You need to get that first, and then split it.  That is three `substring_index()`s:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(base, '|', -2), '|', 1), '-', 1), as source,
       substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(base, '|', -2), '|', 1), '-', -1) as store_loc    
from (select '2019|ACX9|PTG-C|PPP1-MMM1|7986847' as base) x
```